# Verdaccio or Grisaille? Or?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]

I occasionally paint my cityscapes in this manner because I like it, and also because it's a good selling point. I call it grisaille or verdaccio. Both terms are wrong.

**Grisaille** is executed *entirely* in shades of gray, or another neutral color.

**Verdaccio** is a mixture of black, white, and yellow.

Both sound elegantly mysterious and all, but one ought to know the name of one's own product.

To summarize: is there a term for a painting that's mostly black-and-white, with just a splash of color somewhere (not necessarily in the logical center of the composition)?

Comment: Is that Edinburgh?

Comment: @Araucaria: No, it's Verdi Square, New York.

Comment: I suppose you could always coin the term *grisaille colorée.* There is a term *underpainting* which implies the colour is applied on to a completed monochrome image; is that the technique here, or do you simply paint an object directly in colour? [I like it; and the other one you have posted in another question.]

Comment: https://www.icanvas.com/banksy-prints-canvas-art.html Banksy is kinda famous for his black and white stencils with the odd patch of colour, then there's Spielberg's [*girl in a red coat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schindler%27s_List#The_girl_in_red). But I could not find an "official" genre, I think you may have to create your own term.

Comment: You might be interested in hearing this term [*dead colouring*](http://www.essentialvermeer.com/technique/technique_underpainting.html#.VlGyI9KrTDc)

Comment: http://britishlibrary.typepad.co.uk/european/2013/09/macchiaioli-the-italian-impressionists.html and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macchiaioli The term Macchiaioli is close enough, if you desperately desire a name for the mode of painting, *macchia* is also Italian for  "spot", and *macchiato* is espresso coffee with a drop of cold/warm milk.

Answer (score 2):

Your painting is a type of 'chiaroscuro':

> – (Pronounced: key-ARE-oh-SCURE-oh) an Italian word literally meaning “light dark”. Most usually used to describe a painting created with strong contrasts, such as Caravaggio.

From ["Glossary of Oil Painting Terms"](http://willkempartschool.com/glossary-for-oil-painting-terms-the-essential-guide-for-beginners/) at [*Will Kemp Art School*](http://willkempartschool.com/).

An example:

[image: Joseph Wright of Derby, *The Orrery*]

Joseph Wright of Derby, *The Orrery*

Comment: Reference please that a [monochrome](http://painting.about.com/od/artglossarym/g/defmonochrome.htm) painting with the odd splash of colour is a "type" of chiaroscuro. *A monochrome or monochromatic painting is one created using only one color or hue.*

Comment: The OP's example is not monochrome. Why would you think it was? As the citation in my answer states, rather clearly, 'chiaroscuro' describes a painting with strong contrasts. The example I provided shows the effect, masterfully done.

Answer (score 1):

In photography, the term *selective colour* is used for the effect you describe. Here's a [web page](http://www.pxleyes.com/blog/2010/03/50-outstanding-examples-of-selective-color-photography/) found via google with examples of selectively coloured images. Note that like yours, some of the images shown have more than one colour used in an otherwise black and white image.

Answer (score 0):

To ***[colorize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/colorize)*** is the term generally used to refer to adding colour to black-and-white pictures:

> - to cause to appear in color; enhance with color, esp. by computer:
> - To apply color to (black-and-white images) by digital means.

- You are *partially colorizing* a picture.

Comment: No; this means to modify a black-and-white image by adding / substituting colour. Not to create an image that's say 90% black and white.

Comment: Good point, but the words "computer" and "digital" give me pause. Besides, colorize is a verb. "What kind of style is that?" "It's called Partial Colorization." Hmm.