# What would you call this type of photo?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call a photo that is mostly black and white but has been later edited to have color in some place(s), let's say a black and white photo of a woman wearing a skirt of some color. I have zero ideas myself right now but I thought I'd put this out here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_colorization

Comment: Yeah, "colorized" is the modern and most accurately understood yet succinct term.  The term "hand colored" or "hand tinted" is also sometimes used, when the work was indeed done by hand (eg, using water colors).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Verdaccio or Grisaille? Or?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288829/verdaccio-or-grisaille-or)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A  ***[colored photograph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_photography)***  (not color photograph):

> - ***Monochrome images which have been "colorized" by tinting selected areas by hand or mechanically or with the aid of a computer are "colored photographs," not "color photographs."*** Their colors are not dependent on the actual colors of the objects photographed and may be very inaccurate or completely arbitrary.

(Wikipedia)

[image]

Comment: This is true but i think that most people, on hearing the phrase "colored photo" would either mishear it as "color photo" or just assume that you meant "color photo".  Colorized, on the other hand, which you mention in your description, is in much wider use and is a better choice for that reason, i think.

Comment: @MaxWilliams        Please see here: ***colorized photo vs colored photo***.https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=colored+photo%2Ccolorized+photo&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccolored%20photo%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccolorized%20photo%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Josh61 Thanks! I'm almost ashamed that I asked, because the answer is quite obvious. Plus I know it's sometimes done with old BW photos.